# warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] In function ‘char destino(int)’:

Tags: c++, c, warnings

Resulta que me aparece el error en la linea 41, que es la del último }. Y no se que puede estar mal. He probado a poner:

Y no funciona tampoco.

```
    char destino (int posicion) {
    char ciudadDestino; 
    switch (posicion) {
        case 0: 
            return ciudadDestino = 'A';
                break;
        case 1: 
            return ciudadDestino = 'M';
                break;
        case 2: 
            return ciudadDestino = 'B';
                break;

        case 3: 
            return ciudadDestino = 'V';
                break;
        case 4: 
            return ciudadDestino = 'S';
                break;
        default:
                break;
    }  }

}


    ciudadDestino = 'A';    
    return ciudadDestino;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tu problema es que en uno de los casos el switch no va a retornar nada y la funcion no va a retornar ningún valor, tienes que hacer que todos los casos retornen algo, podrías hacer que el default del switch devuelva un char en blanco '0' o algún caracter de tu preferencia o al terminar el switch colocar un return de igual forma.

```
char destino (int posicion) {
char ciudadDestino; 
switch (posicion) {
    case 0: 
        return ciudadDestino = 'A';
            break;
    case 1: 
        return ciudadDestino = 'M';
            break;
    case 2: 
        return ciudadDestino = 'B';
            break;

    case 3: 
        return ciudadDestino = 'V';
            break;
    case 4: 
        return ciudadDestino = 'S';
            break;
    default:
        return '0';
            break;
}

}
```

Comment: Pero no se supone que devuelvo un caracter como A, M, B ...

Comment: Tu esperas un carácter tipo A,M,B.. pero la función en todo caso debe retornar algo. Sino, tendrás ese warning

Answer (score 3):

> > warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] In function ‘char destino(int)’:

La advertencia es provocada porqué el compilador se dio cuenta que la función puede que en alguna situación no retorne ningún valor y eso está incorrecto, debido a que **una función siempre debe devolver un valor**.

**Solución:** Agregar al final de la función un `return` en la cual devuelva cualquier valor (por ejemplo un `-1`). Básicamente con este valor podemos detectar si la función se ejecutó con éxito, debido a que, si se pasa al parámetro `posicion` un valor que no esté en el rango de `0` a `4`, la función debería de retornar un valor en la cual podamos detectar el error.

```
char destino (int posicion) 
{
    char ciudadDestino; 
    switch (posicion) 
    {
    case 0: 
        return ciudadDestino = 'A';
            break;
    case 1: 
        return ciudadDestino = 'M';
            break;
    case 2: 
        return ciudadDestino = 'B';
            break;

    case 3: 
        return ciudadDestino = 'V';
            break;
    case 4: 
        return ciudadDestino = 'S';
            break;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

El modo de uso de la función sería de esta forma:

```
int main()
{  
    char ciudadDestino = destino(4);
    if(ciudadDestino == -1)
        printf("Error:");
    else
        printf("%c\n", ciudadDestino);
    return 0;
}
```

También podríamos reducir el código de la función y ahorrarnos el uso de la sentencia `switch` (consume mucho código).

```
char destino (int posicion) 
{
    const char* ciudadDestino = "AMBVS";
    return (posicion >= 0 && posicion <= 4) ? (ciudadDestino[posicion]) : (-1);
}
```

Básicamente esta nueva función lo que hace es verificar si la posición está en el rango de `0` a `4` y si la comprobación da verdadero, retorna el caracter de X posición de la cadena literal `AMBVS`, de lo contrario, devolverá `-1`, debido a que, se pasó una posición incorrecta.